# how to hide apikeys and other variable in javascript?

Tags: javascript, dotenv

Having trouble hiding the API key and other variables on my website using Javascript. I tried dotenv (`npm install dotenv`) but it did not work. I tried it using:

**1. import**

```
import * as dotenv from 'dotenv'
dotenv.config();
console.log(process.env);
```

**and it runs to an error**

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module
```

**2. require**

```
require('dotenv').config();
```

**also runs to an error**

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined
```

**.env file**

```
apiKey=XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
authDomain=XXXXXXXXXXXXX
etc=etcetera
```

**where were the .env variables will be used**

```
const firebaseConfig = {
    apiKey: process.env.apiKey,
    authDomain: process.env.authDomain,
    databaseURL: process.env.databaseURL,
    projectId: process.env.projectId,
    storageBucket: process.env.storageBucket,
    messagingSenderId: process.env.messagingSenderId,
    appId: process.env.appId,
    measurementId: process.env.measurementId
};

firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
```

Is there a way to make dotenv work? If none, is there any other way to hide API keys?

PS: I've purposely enabled the read and write in firebase and I need to hide api keys and such.

Comment: You can't hide secrets on a client's browser because you can't control the client. In the context of Firebase this means that you should protect your resources which are meant to be accessed without API key by security rules. If you need to use the API key for a specific Firebase service that can't be secured by rules, then you will have to move that logic to a backend, where the API key can securely be stored.

Comment: @Eddi I'm sorry I did not get the last part wherein I will move to backend, can you explain like I'm 5? If moving to the backend is what I should do, can explain how will I use backend? Can I just have another file called `.keys.js` and call it to my `main.js` would that be possible that the `.keys.js` will not be visible to client side?

Comment: It means that you can't directly use your firebase functions on the client side. Instead you will write a dedicated backend with Web API (could be just a small NodeJS backend) which you then call from the client. Ideally you will require authentication for that backend (for which you can use firebase auth). Maybe this can help https://itnext.io/how-to-use-firebase-auth-with-a-custom-node-backend-99a106376c8a

Answer (score -1):

For you to solve the error: `Uncaught SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module`, you'll need to add `"type": "module"` in your `package.json`, then you'll be able to use `import` syntax.

Comment: Sorry I forgot to mention that I've added `"type": "module'` in `package.json`. Still won't work

Comment: Another way to fix this is to set the `type` in your `<script></script>` tag, like this:
`<script type="module" src="path/to/file"></script>`

Comment: I tried setting the `type='module'`, however, I ran into another error `Failed to load module script: Expected a JavaScript module script but the server responded with a MIME type of "text/html". Strict MIME type checking is enforced for module scripts per HTML spec..`

Comment: @ciumai You shouldn't be importing dotenv into a frontend project. It should only be imported into a nodejs backend, similar to how fs should only be imported into a nodejs backend.

Comment: @boreddad420 Got it. I am learning front end and it did not come to mind that backend will be present in this project.